# Tabbed application opens and stays only at splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is all the relevant info/images/code:

[image]

[image]

can't post image of splash screen because I just made my account here at StackOverflow but I assure you, its only a splash screen and nothing else.

There's barely anything going on in the application, the only class that I've modified is the categories class associated with the categories tab. The initial view controller is set to the tab bar controller. Not sure what do do. thanks!

Comment: It looks like the app has crashed. Take a look at the uncaught exception in the console.

Comment: I'll suggest looking at a tutorial of how to manage tableViews, for example this one https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/. That's why the app is freezing in the splash screen, because as @JoGoFo the app crashed and looking at your code you are not making a correct tableview management.